# VS Code numerical arguments

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get rid of emacs. One feature I liked very much was the numerical arguments. This works like this: Ctrl+80 followed by'='. A line is filled with 80 '='. Is there anything comparable in VS code?